# How do I find the sum of numbers from multiple form input values in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

I have 5 inputs that have prices in them.  There is a sixth input that will display the total price by adding the prices of the first five inputs together.

```
function calculateTotal(){

    var priceInputs = document.querySelectorAll("input[name^='tPriceInput']");
    var totalPrice = 0;

    for(var i = 0; i < priceInputs.length; i++){

        totalPrice = totalPrice + parseInt(priceInputs[i].value);

    }

    return totalPrice;

}
```

The function above always returns NaN... Why does this not work?  I have also tried without the parseInt method but that only adds the strings together.

Comment: can u pls share your html in a jdfiddle

Comment: http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_parseint.asp

ParseInt, if a number cannot be returned, NaN is returned.

This means that priceInputs[i].value isn't a number, so your issue most likely lies in `document.querySelectorAll("input[name^='tPriceInput']")`, Do you think maybe it's because you type `^=` instead of `=` ?

Comment: Your code works fine for me: http://jsfiddle.net/9sjbx0s4/

 - - Your issue must rest somewhere else in your code, or you showed us only a snippet of the whole code.

Comment: I would *SPECULATE* that your 6th field, where you want the value to show, also has the name `tPriceInput`, which is causing it's blank value to be added to your totalValue, causing the NaN.

Comment: Pro-tip, you can just say `totalPrice += parseInt(priceInputs[i].value);`

Answer (score 0):

There is not enough info but I assume from all you have said you use commas `,` in the price as a delimeter instead of dots `.`, but JavaScript requires dots. This is a common problem for non-english regional settings.

If so, try this:

```
totalPrice = totalPrice + parseInt(priceInputs[i].value.replace(",", "."));
```

Answer (score -1):

change

```
var priceInputs = document.querySelectorAll("input[name^='tPriceInput']");
```

to

```
var priceInputs = document.querySelectorAll("input[name='tPriceInput']");
```

Comment: what is the difference?

Comment: This is why you dont hijack comments, if I *knew* it was the answer I wouldn't have put it in the comments, I would have put it in the answers section. It was in comments because I was speculating, LOL.

Comment: This is not gonna help.

Comment: If you looked at the timestamps Albert you would see your comment was 4 minutes after my post.  Duh!!